# Overwrite value of objects in Array by property value

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects. How can i take the property from one array and override the 'value' property of the other array? Currently I'm doing this but it seems quite wonky to do it this way.
The original array 'streamingTiles' contains other properties, which is why i have the '...'

Goal is to replace 'value' in streamingTiles with 'counts' value from refTiles based on the matching UID per object

```
const streamingTiles = [
    {uid: 57, value: 10, ...},
    {uid: 30, value: 51, ...},
    {uid: 14, value: 24, ...},
    {uid: 47, value: 73, ...},
]

const refTiles = [
    {uid: 14, counts: 10},
    {uid: 57, counts: 51},
    {uid: 30, counts: 24},
    {uid: 47, counts: 73},
]

// replace value in streamingTiles with 'count' value from refTiles
const tiles = streamingTiles.map((item) => {
  var refObj = refTiles.find((obj) => {
    return obj.uid === item.uid;
  });

  return { ...item, ...{ value: refObj["counts"] } };
});
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

If I renamed 'counts' to be 'value', would the same solution of replacing the 'value' in streamingTiles array with the 'value' from refTiles based on matching UID apply?

```
const streamingTiles = [
    {uid: 57, value: 10, ...},
    {uid: 30, value: 51, ...},
    {uid: 14, value: 24, ...},
    {uid: 47, value: 73, ...},
]

const refTiles = [
    {uid: 14, value: 10},
    {uid: 57, value: 51},
    {uid: 30, value: 24},
    {uid: 47, value: 73},
]
```

Comment: The code looks fine and works, what would be the question?

Comment: @Balastrong For one this code is very inefficient, but it's not clear whether that's what the question is about.

Comment: It is OK if the objects in `streamingTiles` are modified, or do you need to them to stay unmodified?

Comment: @Etheryte how would one make it efficient then that is what im looking for help on?

Comment: @Balastrong objects in streamingTiles needs to remain unmodified

Answer (score 4):

Process the `refTiles` into an object to avoid `find` calls for each item.

```js
const streamingTiles = [
  { uid: 57, value: 10 },
  { uid: 30, value: 51 },
  { uid: 14, value: 24 },
  { uid: 47, value: 73 },
];

const refTiles = [
  { uid: 14, counts: 10 },
  { uid: 57, counts: 51 },
  { uid: 30, counts: 24 },
  { uid: 47, counts: 73 },
];

const refs = refTiles.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ((acc[curr.uid] = curr.counts), acc),
  {}
);

const titles = streamingTiles.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  value: refs[item.uid] ?? item.value,
}));

console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the unnecessary object destruction:

```
const tiles = streamingTiles.map((item) => {
  var refObj = refTiles.find((obj) => {
    return obj.uid === item.uid;
  });

  return { ...item, value: refObj["counts"]};
});
```

Comment: I updated the question in hopes of maybe finding a better solution.